# simple Ruby Class confusing and debugging

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to follow a lesson with the ruby class below, I just don't understand how the results of the output statement is "John Smith" from calling the player function followed by new variable?

Is there any simpler way for this? the coder did it in a way that i got confused
Lastly, Can you tell me how to debug Ruby Class or any ruby code on TextMate? I mean debug just like debugging in Visual C++ shows me what first line gets called and excauted and then jumps to the next etc... to see how it works?

```
class Dungun
  attr_accessor :player 

def initialize(player_name)
  @player = Player.new(player_name)
  @rooms = []
end


class Player
  attr_accessor :name, :location
  def initialize(player_name)
    @name = player_name
  end
end

class Room
  attr_accessor :reference, :name, :description, :connection
  def initialize(reference,name,description,connection)
    @reference = reference
    @name = name
    @description = description
    @connection = connection

  end
end
end

my_dungun = Dungun.new("John Smith")
puts my_dungun.player.name
```

Answer (score 3):

**Execution order**

```
# 1. Called from my_dungun = Dungun.new("John Smith")
Dungun.new("John Smith")

# 2. Inside Dungun it will call the initialize from Dungun class
initialize("John Smith")

# 3. The initialize method, from Dungun class, will have this statement saying
# that instance variable @player will receive the
# result of Player.new("John Smith")
@player = Player.new("John Smith")

# 4. The Player's 'new' method will call the
# inner class Player's initialize method
initialize("John Smith")

# 5. The Player's initialize should assign "Jonh Smith" to @player's name
@name = "John Smith"

# 6. Then head back to where we stopped, and continue to the other
# statement at second line inside Dungun's 'new' method
@rooms = []
```

And read [**Mastering the Ruby Debugger**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GwgF8GcynV0) for a ruby debug gem and some lessons!

Comment: Your code is confusing too, why should i use the @player = Player.new inside of this, there will be more players to be added.

Comment: It isn't code. It is the order that the statements will be called

Comment: I updated my answer, trying to make it better for you @user1556385